# Student's t-distribution value calculation

Tags: r, distributions, t-distribution

I need to calculate the t-distribution values. While referring to literature I found that I need *degrees of freedom* for this. But while referring to my reference paper I find that author has used some tail-area probability value (*P*). For your quick reference said equation is shown as:

[image]

My question is:

1. How should I use the *P* value for *t-value* calculation
2. Is there any existing function in R which uses both of them to calculate t-values. Till now,I have found some functions in R, but all of them use a set of input elements and *degree of freedom*.

Full research paper is present at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/knj0v1ae1fyara4/Using%20intelligent%20data%20analysis.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: If we assume that they refer to the lower tail: `qt(p, df, lower.tail = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, it makes a sense. But, I don't know if I set `lower.tail =FALSE` , then I used to get positive value otherwise output is a negative value. Significance of positive and negative is not clear. In R manual, difference is not clear.

Comment: The centered t-distribution has negative quantiles at its left tail. The documentation is extremely clear: "if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x], otherwise, P[X > x]"

Comment: @Roland Ok. I tried, both of these. It did not affect too much. Please write your first comment as an answer so that I can close this question.

Comment: You need to find out which they mean in the paper. I'd guess the former, but haven't read the paper.

Comment: In the mentioned reference  Rosner [12], the author has mentioned that `t _d,p` represents the `pth` percentile of a `t` distribution  with `d` degrees of freedom. This confirms that `qt( )` function is doing the same